# Problema com leitura de arquivo .WAV

Tags: c, c++, matlab, áudio

Olá, estou tentando ler um arquivo .wav de 5s repleto de "silêncio" para testar o código em C. Consegui ler o cabeçalho porem ao tentar extrair o campo de data onde contem o conteúdo em sí ( que acredito que deveria ser zero) gera alguns números. conforme as imagens abaixo.

**Código:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buff[10000];
int main(){

    int i;
    FILE * fp;
    FILE *flog;

    if ((fp = fopen("Silencio2.wav", "rb")) == NULL){
        printf("Fail!");
        exit(1);
    }


    fseek(fp, 44, 0); // Lê apartir do campo DATA como segue na documentação.
    fread(buff,sizeof(int),1024,fp);
    flog = fopen("Silencio2.txt","w"); // Cria um log para jogar no matlab e gerar o gráfico

    // Imprime em hexadecimal para visualizar melhor e salva em decimal no log.
    for(i = 0; i < 5000 ; i++){
     printf("%i == %hhx \n",i,buff[i]);
     fprintf(flog,"%d\n",buff[i]);
     buff[i] = 0;
    }
    fclose(flog);
    return 0;
}
```

Imagem da Leitura do Header .Wav:

[image: Saída do Header, pelo meu programa.]

Como podemos notar o programa lê corretamente o header trazendo as informações coerentes, RIFF, WAVE, FMT, 1 canal, 16bits, 16khz e o inicio do data (40~44).

**Fonte que estou usando para ler o arquivo .wav:**
http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

**Características do arquivo .wav:**

```
Bitrate: 16 bits PCM;
Canais: 1;
SampleRate: 16khz.
Tempo: 5s;
Gerado pelo Audacity com a função de gerar silencio.
```

Após salvar este log em txt estou colando o mesmo no **matlab** e lendo o arquivo original no mesmo, afim de imprimir o gráfico comparativo entre os 2 para validar os meus dados, porem estou obtendo a seguinte saída:

**1º Grafico Processamento do matlab com a função readaudio();**
**2º Grafico saida do log do meu código;**

[image: Comparação MATLAB x Meu Código]

**Script Matlab:**

```
[Sile2,Fs] = audioread('Silencio2.wav');
title('Gerado pelo MATLAB');
subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(CodeSile2);
title('Meu código');
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(Sile2);
```

**A questão que fica é:**
Meus resultados estão coerentes? Pois alem da divergência de magnitude do sinal há um ruído, que não sei explicar o porque do mesmo. Sendo que o sinal foi gerado através de um gerador de silêncio.

**PS: Sim conheço a libsnd porem como quero embarcar este código em um stm32/esp32, quanto menos bibliotecas utilizar melhor.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem alguns erros acontecendo no seu código...

Ok vc pulou diretamente para o Byte que contem os dados do arquivo de áudio aqui:

```
fseek(fp, 44, 0);
```

Na próxima linha leu `1024` bytes:

```
fread(buff,sizeof(int),1024,fp);
```

Logo depois dentro do seu `while` você esta tentando caminhar até o `byte 5000` ? como se vc só leu no buffer `1024` ? Certamente ele leu corretamente as `1024` primeiras posições dentro do seu `while` e depois disso começou a pegar sujeira, este é o problema principal do seu código.

Ou você lê o tamanho total de bytes do seu áudio e armazena no buffer ou vai caminhando acessando pedaço por pedaço dentro do loop, detalhe o tamanho atual do `buff` não possui capacidade para armazenar tudo, vc definiu ele como sendo `buff[10000];` se quiser jogar os `5` segundos inteiros dentro do seu buffer precisaria de `80000`:

SampleRate: 16khz.
Tempo: 5s;

```
16000*5 = 80000
```

Claro que a segunda opção é a mais esperta, ler os bytes por pedaços é a alternativa mais sensata e eficiente, você deve pensar em algo funcionando assim:

```
fseek(fp, 44, 0); // Lê apartir do campo DATA como segue na documentação.



//enquanto tiver dados para ler
do{

// a cada iteração captura 1024 bytes
byte_read=fread(buff,sizeof(int),1024,fp);

 //ler os 1024 bytes do buffer acima
 for(i = 0; i < 1024 ; i++){
     printf("%i == %hhx \n",i,buff[i]);
     fprintf(flog,"%d\n",buff[i]);
     buff[i] = 0;
  }

//enquanto tiver dados para ler
}while(byte_read > 0)
```

Outra coisa, para comparar os dados do seu `.txt` com o valor do matlab você vai precisar converter o valor que está salvando em decimal para float point (isso responde sobre a divergência de magnitude do sinal), o matlab representa a forma de onda de um arquivo de áudio decodificado em float point, os valores flutuam entre `-1 e 1`, o áudio que está decodificando em `C` é `16 bits`, por padrão se forem representados em decimais vão flutuar entre `-32768 e 32767`, então para converter os seus valores para baterem com os valores do matlab vc deverá converter para float point usando a equação `seuNumDecimal/32768.0`

Comment: Muito Obrigado, realmente não tinha me dado conta deste detalhe fazendo o ajuste no matlab e pegando o tamanho da amostra certa deu super certo! Abraço.

PS: Exatamente vou fazer a leitura por partes como indicado , eu estava buscando entender primeiramente se o código era funcional desta forma.

Comment: que bom @GabrielLavoura é sempre bom ajudar :-)